# Cordova iOS Go Back To Previous Page

Tags: cordova, ipad, ios9

I am not very familiar with iOS. I have a Cordova app that I built and it runs fine on Android. However when I run it on an iPad running iOS 9 there are no back buttons to travel back to the previous page like any browser I have ever used in my life. I'm assuming its loaded into a UIWebView so how am I supposed to travel back to the previous page when there is no back button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a custom "backButton" equivalent to Android or Windows Phone native back buttons.

In my case, I created an "Arrow to Left" button in left top corner of the screen to work as backButton. After, I linked my backButton function for Android e WP to it. Look:

**HTML:**

```
<span id="iosBackButton" ng-click="iosBackButtonEvent()"><i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>&nbsp;Back</span>
```

**JS:**

```
//Android and WP cordova handle
//document.addEventListener('backbutton', backButtonActions, false);

//Only iOS
$scope.iosBackButtonEvent= function() {
        try {
            backButtonActions();
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
```

**PS:** I use AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add your own.

If you use a framework like Ionic this is already baked in.

Answer (score 0):

This would work 100 % of times. Add **$ionicViewSwitcher** and **$ionicHistory** to your controller or function. and then ng-click="goBackState()"

```
$rootScope.goBackState = function(){
  $ionicViewSwitcher.nextDirection('back');
  //console.log($ionicHistory.backView())  
  $ionicHistory.goBack(); 
}
```